# Fullcalendar - Adjusting Calendar View Day Display Range for Custom Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm building an application that records and displays daily events from  5am - 5am.

I'm using Fullcalendar to display these event in a month view. Based on this, I need to display 5am - 5am as belonging to a single day (ex. Monday).

For instance, on Monday I have 3 events:

1. 7am to 11am
2. 1pm to 12:30am (event spans Monday and Tuesday)
3. 1am to 3am (event is effectively on Tuesday; however, I want it to
   display on Monday)

Ideally, I'm going to add a parameter, dayStartTime, which is a custom day start time offset maintaining a 24-hour range.

My question is where within the FullCalendar plugin is it that needs to be modified to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

try this - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Duration/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

header: {

    center: 'month,agendaFourDay' // buttons for switching between views
},
views: {
    agendaFourDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 4 },
        buttonText: '4 day'
    }
}
});
```

For duration

```
"23:59"       // hours/minutes
"23:59:59"    // hours/minutes/seconds
"1.23:59:59"  // days/hours/minutes/seconds
{ days:1, hours:23, minutes:59 } // an object
```